# Can Not Overlay div Over Full Screen Canvas for Unity WebGL Build

Tags: html, css, unity-game-engine, html5-canvas, webgl

I want to overlay a div in front of full-screen Unity - Canvas. I can overlay it when it is not full screen but can not figure out how to overlay div front of Unity Canvas while canvas is in full-screen mode.

I made a loading CSS in the index.html file of the Unity WebGL build. That I paste below.

```
<style>
  .loader {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: -76px 0 0 -76px;
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid #babfc2;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  }
  
  /* Safari */
  @-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
  }
  
  @keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
  }
  </style>
    <div id="modelLoading" class="loader"></div>
```

I use this CSS as a class for a div, Basically, div shows up in a normal window as seen in the image below, but it disappears in the full-screen window. Also tried: fullscreen things but didn't work.

I add screenshots and the full HTML code below.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Unity WebGL Player | DeleteThisWebGLMultiThreadWorks2</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="TemplateData/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TemplateData/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      .loader {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        z-index: 999;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        margin: -76px 0 0 -76px;
        border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-top: 16px solid #babfc2;
        -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
        animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      }
      
      /* Safari */
      @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
        100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
      }
      
      @keyframes spin {
        0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
        100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
      }
      </style>
        <div id="modelLoading" class="loader"></div>

    <div id="unity-container" class="unity-desktop">
      <canvas id="unity-canvas" width=960 height=600>
      </canvas>
      <div id="unity-loading-bar">
        <div id="unity-logo"></div>
        <div id="unity-progress-bar-empty">
          <div id="unity-progress-bar-full"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="unity-warning"> </div>
      <div id="unity-footer">
        <div id="unity-webgl-logo"></div>
        <div id="unity-fullscreen-button"></div>
        <div id="unity-build-title">DeleteThisWebGLMultiThreadWorks2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var container = document.querySelector("#unity-container");
      var canvas = document.querySelector("#unity-canvas");
      var loadingBar = document.querySelector("#unity-loading-bar");
      var progressBarFull = document.querySelector("#unity-progress-bar-full");
      var fullscreenButton = document.querySelector("#unity-fullscreen-button");
      var warningBanner = document.querySelector("#unity-warning");

      // Shows a temporary message banner/ribbon for a few seconds, or
      // a permanent error message on top of the canvas if type=='error'.
      // If type=='warning', a yellow highlight color is used.
      // Modify or remove this function to customize the visually presented
      // way that non-critical warnings and error messages are presented to the
      // user.
      function unityShowBanner(msg, type) {
        function updateBannerVisibility() {
          warningBanner.style.display = warningBanner.children.length ? 'block' : 'none';
        }
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = msg;
        warningBanner.appendChild(div);
        if (type == 'error') div.style = 'background: red; padding: 10px;';
        else {
          if (type == 'warning') div.style = 'background: yellow; padding: 10px;';
          setTimeout(function() {
            warningBanner.removeChild(div);
            updateBannerVisibility();
          }, 5000);
        }
        updateBannerVisibility();
      }

      var buildUrl = "Build";
      var loaderUrl = buildUrl + "/DeleteThisTryingMultiThreadWebGL8.loader.js";
      var config = {
        dataUrl: buildUrl + "/DeleteThisTryingMultiThreadWebGL8.data.gz",
        frameworkUrl: buildUrl + "/DeleteThisTryingMultiThreadWebGL8.framework.js.gz",
        codeUrl: buildUrl + "/DeleteThisTryingMultiThreadWebGL8.wasm.gz",
        streamingAssetsUrl: "StreamingAssets",
        companyName: "DefaultCompany",
        productName: "DeleteThisWebGLMultiThreadWorks2",
        productVersion: "0.1",
        showBanner: unityShowBanner,
      };

      // By default Unity keeps WebGL canvas render target size matched with
      // the DOM size of the canvas element (scaled by window.devicePixelRatio)
      // Set this to false if you want to decouple this synchronization from
      // happening inside the engine, and you would instead like to size up
      // the canvas DOM size and WebGL render target sizes yourself.
      // config.matchWebGLToCanvasSize = false;

      if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        // Mobile device style: fill the whole browser client area with the game canvas:

        var meta = document.createElement('meta');
        meta.name = 'viewport';
        meta.content = 'width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=yes';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
        container.className = "unity-mobile";

        // To lower canvas resolution on mobile devices to gain some
        // performance, uncomment the following line:
        // config.devicePixelRatio = 1;

        canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
        canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';

        unityShowBanner('WebGL builds are not supported on mobile devices.');
      } else {
        // Desktop style: Render the game canvas in a window that can be maximized to fullscreen:

        canvas.style.width = "960px";
        canvas.style.height = "600px";
      }

      loadingBar.style.display = "block";

      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = loaderUrl;
      script.onload = () => {
        createUnityInstance(canvas, config, (progress) => {
          progressBarFull.style.width = 100 * progress + "%";
        }).then((unityInstance) => {
          loadingBar.style.display = "none";
          fullscreenButton.onclick = () => {
            unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1);
          };
        }).catch((message) => {
          alert(message);
        });
      };
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `CSS show up`? CSS is a style sheet that defines how certain elements shall look like / behave ... if these elements are not visible because you are in full screen mode than the CSS has nothing to do ...

Comment: Sorry for the wrong definition, I don't know much about front end things. Actually as you warn, there is a div which has a CSS as its class. That div show up in normal mode but does not show up in full screen. In CSS there is a :fullscreen class can be defined that can change behaviour of CSS in full screen mode, so thats why I suppose its related with CSS.

Comment: Sorry I really don't understand what exactly you are trying to achieve. If you enter full screen mode it is intended that only the WebGL player is visible no further HTML content ... you can leave full screen by hitting escape

Comment: I just simplified the question, I actually load 3D models at runtime but while model loading WebGL screen freeze and do not response at that time. I just wanna make a loading screen without WebGL so users must not realize that WebGL freezed.

Comment: Ah now I get it. You mean that loading circle thingy disappears due to the fullscreen. There are not many options I guess: Either built this into Unity itself and make your object loading as "async" as possible, or use a special JavaScript code your c# code can [interact](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) with and invoke certain evens on which you enable and disable that loading overlay / element and exit / hide the WebGL content meanwhile

Comment: Yes, its is. Thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunateely I can not make loading things in unity with async, I made an another scene that load async but that one also freeze in webGL . I think due to there is no multi thread support in WebGL. Secondly I use JS interaction as you suggest for that enabling a div element that show loading with help of CSS. It works as I wanted in normal window but disappears in full screen window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of asking unity library to make canvas fullscreen you can make entire canvas container
[fullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) yourself using JavaScript and DOM APIs.
This way you'll have more control. See below demo code. Explanation is in the code comments.
As you haven't shared your CSS and javascript libraries I've added my own style for demo purpose.

Put this entire code in a local .html file and run it in a browser. Then press `Fullscreen`. You'll notice that the spinning loader is in fullscreen along with the canvas.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Unity WebGL Player | DeleteThisWebGLMultiThreadWorks2</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="TemplateData/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="TemplateData/style.css">
  <style>
    .loader {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      z-index: 999;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      margin: -76px 0 0 -76px;
      border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-top: 16px solid #babfc2;
      -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    }

    /* Safari */

    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      }

      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

    @keyframes spin {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }

      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

    /* new rules ********/

    #unity-container {
      width: 97vw;
      height: 90vh;
      border: 3px solid orange;
      background-color: gray;
    }

    #fullScreenContainer {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #unity-canvas {
      background-color: black;
      /* note the dimensions are in percentages */
      /* they'll scale with parent, as parent goes fullscreen*/
      /* the canvas will grow as well*/
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #unity-fullscreen-button {
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: fit-content;
      color: Orange;
      font-size: 2em;
    }

    #unity-fullscreen-button:hover {
      background-color: lightgreen;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="unity-container" class="unity-desktop">

    <!-- take this container fullscreen instead of taking only the canvas -->
    <div id="fullScreenContainer">
      <div id="modelLoading" class="loader"></div>
      <canvas id="unity-canvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div id="unity-footer">
      <div id="unity-fullscreen-button">FullScreen</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var container = document.querySelector("#unity-container");
    var fullContainer = document.querySelector("#fullScreenContainer");
    var fullscreenButton = document.querySelector("#unity-fullscreen-button");

    fullscreenButton.onclick = () => {
      //don't request fullscreen on unityinstance
      //unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1);

      //let's take things fullscreen ourselves
      //request fullscreen on the wrapper
      fullContainer.requestFullscreen();
      //you might want to resize canvas to fit screen.

    };

    //ignore this just for the demo
    var canvas = document.getElementById("unity-canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "bold 24px verdana, sans-serif";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillText("The Game", 150, 80);

    ctx.closePath();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I think if you debug `unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1)` in chrome developer console then you'll find that it does similar thing: resizing canvas and calling `requestFullscreen()` on it.

**Note:** StackOverflow and other online html editors do not allow fullscreen so you'll have to try the code in local .html file.

---

With fix your code will look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title> Xplore 3D Model Editor</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="TemplateData/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="TemplateData/style.css">
  <style>
    #modelLoading {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      margin: -76px 0 0 -76px;
      border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-top: 16px solid #babfc2;
      -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    }

    #modelLoading:fullscreen {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      margin: -76px 0 0 -76px;
      border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-top: 16px solid #babfc2;
      -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    }

    /* Safari */
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      }

      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

    @keyframes spin {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }

      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="unity-container" class="unity-desktop">
    <div id="modelLoadingContainer">
      <div id="modelLoading"></div>
      <!-- //*** removed inline dimensions. setting inline style is not good -->
      <canvas id="unity-canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="unity-loading-bar">
      <div id="unity-logo"></div>
      <div id="unity-progress-bar-empty">
        <div id="unity-progress-bar-full"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="unity-warning"> </div>
    <div id="unity-footer">
      <div id="unity-webgl-logo"></div>

      <div id="unity-fullscreen-button">
      </div>
      <div id="unity-build-title">Xplore 3D Model Editor</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var container = document.querySelector("#unity-container");
    var canvas = document.querySelector("#unity-canvas");
    var loadingBar = document.querySelector("#unity-loading-bar");
    var progressBarFull = document.querySelector("#unity-progress-bar-full");
    var fullscreenButton = document.querySelector("#unity-fullscreen-button");
    var warningBanner = document.querySelector("#unity-warning");
    var modelLoading = document.getElementById('modelLoading');

    function EnableModelLoading() {
      document.getElementById("modelLoading").style.display = "";
    }
    function DisableleModelLoading() {
      document.getElementById("modelLoading").style.display = "none";
    }

    // Shows a temporary message banner/ribbon for a few seconds, or
    // a permanent error message on top of the canvas if type=='error'.
    // If type=='warning', a yellow highlight color is used.
    // Modify or remove this function to customize the visually presented
    // way that non-critical warnings and error messages are presented to the
    // user.
    function unityShowBanner(msg, type) {
      function updateBannerVisibility() {
        warningBanner.style.display = warningBanner.children.length ? 'block' : 'none';
      }
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = msg;
      warningBanner.appendChild(div);
      if (type == 'error') div.style = 'background: red; padding: 10px;';
      else {
        if (type == 'warning') div.style = 'background: yellow; padding: 10px;';
        setTimeout(function () {
          warningBanner.removeChild(div);
          updateBannerVisibility();
        }, 5000);
      }
      updateBannerVisibility();
    }

    var buildUrl = "Build";
    var loaderUrl = buildUrl + "/Xplore3DModelEditorOnHeroku5.loader.js";
    var config = {
      dataUrl: buildUrl + "/Xplore3DModelEditorOnHeroku5.data.unityweb",
      frameworkUrl: buildUrl + "/Xplore3DModelEditorOnHeroku5.framework.js.unityweb",
      codeUrl: buildUrl + "/Xplore3DModelEditorOnHeroku5.wasm.unityweb",
      streamingAssetsUrl: "StreamingAssets",
      companyName: "Timelooper",
      productName: "Xplore 3D Model Editor",
      productVersion: "0.1",
      showBanner: unityShowBanner,
    };

    // By default Unity keeps WebGL canvas render target size matched with
    // the DOM size of the canvas element (scaled by window.devicePixelRatio)
    // Set this to false if you want to decouple this synchronization from
    // happening inside the engine, and you would instead like to size up
    // the canvas DOM size and WebGL render target sizes yourself.
    // config.matchWebGLToCanvasSize = false;

    if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      container.className = "unity-mobile";
      // Avoid draining fillrate performance on mobile devices,
      // and default/override low DPI mode on mobile browsers.
      config.devicePixelRatio = 1;
      unityShowBanner('WebGL builds are not supported on mobile devices.');
    } else {
      //*** changes set minWidth instead of fixed width 
      canvas.style.minWidth = "960px";
      canvas.style.minHeight = "600px";
      //100% will ensure canvas will be of parent size
      canvas.style.width = "100%";
      canvas.style.height = "100%";
    }
    loadingBar.style.display = "block";

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = loaderUrl;
    script.onload = () => {
      //DisableleModelLoading();
      createUnityInstance(canvas, config, (progress) => {
        progressBarFull.style.width = 100 * progress + "%";
      }).then((unityInstance) => {
        loadingBar.style.display = "none";
        //*** hide loading
        modelLoading.style.display = "none";
      }).catch((message) => {
        alert(message);
      });
    };

    document.getElementById('unity-fullscreen-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
      var elem = document.getElementById('modelLoadingContainer');
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
      if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
        elem.requestFullscreen();
      } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
        elem.msRequestFullscreen();
      } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
      }
    });
    document.body.appendChild(script);

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

You may have to adjust style on `fullScreenContainer` element.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, now loading div shows up in full screen mode but game doesn't show up and there is only "The Game" text can be seen front of black screen, if I delete ctx part then only black screen shows up with loading CSS.

Comment: They may be creating their own canvas element. Without my fix check in the Chrome Devloper Tools that under `unity-container` html element is their a new canvas.  Like they've done here in this [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/webgl-globe-2?file=index.html) Or [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/6jk6u?file=/public/index.html). I don't have the dev environment setuped if you could share a minimum demo app without my fix on stackblitz or codesandbox would be great.

Comment: I've updated the answer added how entire code will look like with fix. In case you've missed the createUnityInstance parth.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. When I apply your fix full screen button disappears and game canvas become larger, if I delete CSS part it show up normal first but after full screen game stays at left side. Here is the real project that I am trying to develop https://akinerkan.itch.io/xplore-3d-model-editor, you can click load model from url button and paste that https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/pogicm0vczh7njc/garuda-and-vishnu-obj.zip?dl=0 for testing. Also if you want the direct download link of the project https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/uictue36sbnbbxl/Xplore3DModelEditor.zip?dl=0

Comment: It was a minor styling issue. I've removed inline style and added percentage styles also hid the lading spinner after content loaded. Now it shows when you load for the first time and when you load model as well. Here is [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/aNgKDqRC) . Search `//***` to see the changes. Cool model btw!

Comment: Yes, I found it on Artec3d for demo things like that :) You may refactor your answer above according to your last changes to help Unity Developers like me who is a lamer in front end things :) In conclusion, thank you so much for all off your help.